# JavaScript Fadeout Transition

Tags: javascript, transition

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, wondering how I could add a fadeout transition to the following script?  Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var curimg=0
        function rotateimages(){
            document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "images/"+galleryarray[curimg])
            curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
        }
        window.onload=function(){
            setInterval("rotateimages()", 10000)
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I recommend using jQuery's `.fadeOut()` method. http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: Yeah. I figured it out shortly after posting this. Thanks though!

Comment: OK. Maybe I'm missing something here. I added the .fadeOut() method to setInterval("rotateimage()", 10000).fadeOut("slow") and it's not working.

Comment: You want to use it inside `rotateimages()`, I'll post an answer with an example in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To do this easily we will want to use jQuerys `.fadeOut()` method on the slideshow. When `rotateimages()` is called we want to fade the sideshow element out, then to show the slideshow again (I'll fade the next image in so we have a smooth effect).

```
function rotateimages() 
{
    $( "#slideshow" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "images/" + galleryarray[curimg].src)
        curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
    });
    $( "#slideshow" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
}
```

In this case what we are doing is fading the `#slideshow` element itself.

[**Here is a Fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/5mka5yfc/) with some minor changes, I've added some generic images. We end up with a nice slideshow effect.

Comment: Is it possible to add a short video in the slider so that when it loads, it automatically plays?

Comment: @FrankieBermudez Probably, you could use the HTML 5 `<video>` tag, and change it's `src` properties. Then using `play()` on `fadeIn`. That is, the video being like an `img` element in the slideshow correct?

Comment: I see your logic. I actually tried adding a 4th variable and changed the src to point to the video. It failed to load, perhaps the reason I didn't add play() on fadeIn.  I did a few searches, not much luck.

Comment: The problem is that you are using an `<img>` tag and not a `<video>` tag. What video files are you using?

Comment: I'm using mp4 as the video format. I added this 4th variable:
var img4 = new Image();
                img4.src = "src/video.mp4";
Am I going to use both <img> and <video> tags in the HTML?

Comment: For the video you will just be using the file name as a string, since videos are not images, you can't say `var img4 = new Image()`. And note we will need to switch to the `<video>` element. There is quite a bit complexity in this. I recommend asking this as a separate question. Due to how SO is organized; it's usually a bad idea to ask multiple question in a single post.